# Unable to get scope permission from G suite marketplace app

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, drive, google-apps-marketplace

I have created a marketplace app to capture google drive changes.
Enabled two API & services.
1) Google Drive API
2) G Suite Marketplace SDK

Added required content in marketplace SDK and it is published via google chrome tool. So, got a marketplace app url which I can share with others and can install app in their domain.

With this app url I have installed an app by clicking on "DOMAIN INSTALL" button.
In order to receive notification of each drive changes my script is trying to create a channel for each user under this domain But, channel is not getting created. It shows error called "invalid_grant"

So, I took another approach to add marketplace client id and scope permissions under Admin Console->security->Advance Setting ->Manage API client access manually.
Now, I am able to create a channel for user in domain and can access drive files content.

Please help me to figure out that why I am not able to get permission while installing a published G suite marketplace app?

Thanks you.